# Is there an Android Guy icon

Tags: android-icons

Is there a Android Guy icon out there anywhere? I am looking for one to put on my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good 'Android Guy' in the [font-awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) icon-font - easy to add,use, but not a classic glyphicon: [fontawesome.io/icon/android](http://fontawesome.io/icon/android)